# Location for laravel blade views

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm brand new to laravel, and after battling to get all the pieces installed, I'm finally working through the bootcamp at https://bootcamp.laravel.com/blade/creating-chirps. The registration / login part all worked well, but now I'm trying to implement the page for creating 'chirps.'

The first step to display 'Hello World!' worked fine, so I know my Controller is ok up to that point. I then added the view and created the view in PATH/resources/views/chirps/index.blade.php as below.

app/Http/Controllers/ChirpController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Chirp;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChirpController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        return 'Hello, World!';
        return view('chirps.index');
    }
...
```

resources/views/chirps/index.blade.php

```
<x-app-layout>
    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto p-4 sm:p-6 lg:p-8">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('chirps.store') }}">
            @csrf
            <textarea
                name="message"
                placeholder="{{ __('What\'s on your mind?') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('message') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('message')" class="mt-2" />
            <x-primary-button class="mt-4">{{ __('Chirp') }}</x-primary-button>
        </form>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

I see the update in my 'run npm dev' panel, but when I view the page I still only see 'Hello World' without any css.

I'm going through the docs trying to understand how it all fits together, but I haven't yet found anything that explains why index.blade.php is 'index' or why it's in a 'chirps' folder. I've tried saving the file as:

- resources/views/chirps/index.blade.php
- resources/views/chirps.index.blade.php
- resources/views/Chirps/index.blade.php
- resources/views/chirps/chirps.blade.php
- resources/views/chirps.blade.php
  but none of them have any impact on the page.

I would expect to see something in the logs but when I refresh the page there is no change to storage/logs/laravel.log. Is there somewhere else I can look?

So I guess I have a number of questions.

- Is resources/views/chirps/index.blade.php the correct location for the view?
- How do I find logs to say whether it's loading the view or not?
- What else am I missing?

Comment: You can't have 2 return statements in a row... `return 'Hello, World!'; return view('chirps.index');` will ***always*** return `Hello, World!'`. The 2nd line is never hit. Remove that first line. Sidenote, if you use a proper Code Editor or IDE, this will be highlighted as "Unreachable code detected" 

Comment: The location of `views` are in `resources/views` if you are using `HTML`. Also in `view('chirps.index')` the `chirps` is the folder while the `index` is the filename without the`.blade.php`.

Comment: Seriously? Why wouldn't they say that in the tutorial?

Comment: view('folder.filename'). Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm... I missed a red highlight on the first return that's not really clear on the screen. I'll need to turn up the brightness and look more closely throughout the rest of the tutorial.

Comment: Or, `view('folder.folder.folder.filename')`; basically, assume anything before the last `.whatever` is a folder. Also, [it does say this in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#nested-view-directories). If you were following a tutorial that didn't include this information, then it should probably be updated to note that  Also, last note, the double-return is a PHP thing (and many languages). Certain keywords, like `return` immediately stop any subsequent execution in the function/etc. Some are more intense, like `exit`, or `die`, etc., which stop _all_ subsequent execution.

Comment: If I'd been coding vanilla php, I think I would have noticed the double return, but because so much of laravel is unfamiliar, I guess I assumed that was normal. My 'seriously?' was for not making it clear that the previous 'return' line needed to be deleted. In fact, it was clear once I looked closer at the highlights. But, yes, the explanations in general leave a lot to be desired, including, as you say, the links between files. I'm now stuck on an error for a missing table that doesn't appear anywhere in the whole project (except in the error logs).

Comment: Totally understandable! Laravel is a great framework, and you can learn both it and PHP at the same time, but having an understanding of the base language for any framework is always a good idea, if for nothing else than to learn basic syntax. As for your new error, it's like a Table being derived from a Model. Keep trying, check the documentation or search Stackoverflow for a similar error. If you get completely stuck, feel free to ask a new question. Cheers!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Lewis for pointing out the (obvious) answer. The function was stopping at 'return "Hello World"' and was never reaching 'return view()'. I needed to delete the first return.

Comment: What a stupid categorisation of this problem. It is absolutely reproducible and is not a typo. It was caused by a lack of understanding of Laravel (and php in general I guess) that any beginner could make, and I'm sure someone will find it useful.